# How to stop being labeled in a certain way by one's boss?

Tags: communication, management, colleagues

Recently I noticed that my boss labels me in a particular way in conversations with me, and in meetings with other higher-ups and colleagues. The label appears to be intended as a compliment and is generally viewed as a positive quality. However I feel that this particular label projects a very narrow and distorted impression of myself as a team member and colleague. I am not thrilled with it and would like for this labeling to stop. Also I feel the label itself is not relevant to this question so I will leave it out.

**How should I address the issue and communicate to the boss that I do not appreciate such labeling?** The relationship with the boss is generally positive but this person does view me as a potential competitor and will likely not take direct feedback or criticism well. Are there subtle ways to get the point across without risking the current relationship, or will only a very direct approach work?

The issue of labeling employees seems to be a thing, but resources like [this](https://www.smartmeetings.com/magazine_article/pros-cons-labeling-employees) focus on the pros and cons of this practice for managers, rather than what the subordinate could do about it. The article correctly points out that labeling creates a bias and limits the perception of an employee's full worth. The words we use to describe others do frame how we and others see them. However there is little advice on how the employee being labeled should address the issue.

Although I do not disagree that the label highlights one of my qualities, I would prefer that it not be used to describe me and shape others' impression of me, even if intended as a positive. I have other strengths and do not feel that this is the greatest of them. I would rather not be labeled in any particular way at all. "Success" would mean the boss not using any labels in describing me. I cannot prevent others from discussing me behind my back but I would at least like this labeling to stop in my presence.

I am interested in others' experiences with being labeled by their boss or colleagues, and how to best navigate this to stop this practice.

Comment: 5 paragraphs, 350 words, and not one clear example of the actual label you are objecting to.  This makes your "question" seem more of a philosophical rant than a problem to be solved.

Comment: @PeterM I intentionally kept the question generic, since the specific label should not impact the approach to addressing the issue and is therefore irrelevant for purposes of answering. You are welcome to think of one and insert if it helps you come up with an answer.

Comment: And that's the whole point of my comment.  Without a concrete example to work with there is no possibility of a concrete answer.  Which IMHO relegates this to a discussion - which is something that I should not have to tell you to go read the help center as to what sort of questions should be avoided.

Comment: https://www.monster.ca/career-advice/article/50-personality-traits-for-the-workplace-canada - pick any one.

Comment: So just for context the label is something along the lines of "geek" or "excel-wizard" and not something vaguely degrading  like "girl" "boy" or gods forbid some kind of endearing slur or ethnic remark?

Comment: Have you asked your boss to stop referring to you by the label you object to?

Comment: @Borgh Yup, along those lines.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand why no one else posted that comment earlier, and I have added that as an answer itself.

Comment: @A.S I see this as on topic as is and will vote to reopen if enough votes come in to close.  The fact that you are concerned with being pigeon holed is enough context.

Comment: @Myles Thanks for your support! I am not sure what caused all the downvotes as the question seems to meet all guidelines and be tied to a real known issue in the field. My guess is folks got tripped up by the ambiguity of lacking the specific label, however as I noted earlier I see that as immaterial and not impacting the quality of the general question.

Comment: @A.S, Those are traits, not labels. You must have linked to the wrong page. I'm with Peter on this. It would just be easier if you revealed the label given to you.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The problem with giving the specific label is it leads down the "I wouldn't be bothered by being called that so neither should you" road that ignores that the OP is bothered so it is a problem.  The OP is concerned that a label with overshadow their broad set of skills so that is enough to address the question.  This is evidenced by really good answers from both Richard and Sourav with the level of detail given.

Comment: @A.S As a suggestion I would edit that you aren't going to share what the label is as an early part of the question text.  Just based on how it's laid out I had to read the question twice just to be sure I didn't miss some label.

Comment: @Myles, I really don't think I would react that way. The problem with many "positive" labels is that they can be over the top and as a result kind of patronizing and backhanded. And depending on the label itself, we may be able to find the perfect retort like: "You can just call me God" or "John, I only told you to call me that in the bedroom." or "John is just being modest. I've learned everything about HTML from him." or "Thanks John, I really needed the pep talk" or "Thanks John! John has my mother on speed dial. She told him to say this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot escape labels, and we humans need them as a form of shorthand.  What you do is you give the label meaning, or act to earn a different label/nickname.

I've had numerous over the years from "the hacker" to "Devil man", to "Loki", and many, many others.  If I want to ditch those kinds of labels, the obvious route would be to be less mischievous.  That said, I don't have any labels like "The jerk", "The @sshole", et cetera.

There is no way to eliminate labels, nor should you want there to be.  Labels/nicknames are what show us how the world sees us.  If there's something you don't like about the label you are given, then change what it is in yourself that earned you that label to begin with.

**TLDR:** If you want to get your people to stop slapping you with a particular label, then change what you need to change so that the label does not apply.

Comment: Thanks, agreed. As I thought more about the issue I came to a similar viewpoint. You don't necessary want to "undo" a positive label. The other path is to develop oneself in ways that will eventually cause the old label to become less relevant and naturally fall away or be 'upgraded' to something better.

Answer (score 16):

> *How should I address the issue and communicate to the boss that I do not appreciate such labeling?*

Since you have a *generic* question, I'll provide a *generic* answer: If you do not like something, speak up. No one is going to read your mind.

There's no way you can keep everyone (including you) happy. If you don't want to be called X, just have a private chat with your boss and say:

> *"Hey Boss, I'm actually not comfortable being called X, can we avoid that please?"*

Any sensible person, will understand your point of view and will stop using that phrase / label immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If the label is positive, what’s the problem?

Your boss just picked one of your positive attributes to describe you to the group. Same way we pick strong for steel, bright for the sun, cold for winter etc.

It would be a really long introduction if he describes you to at a level of precision to fully describe you... or any person for that matter.

If you want to be called your name, just respond with “it’s A.S” and call it a day.

Comment: I thought I was clear about the problem: even though the label is positive, I feel it narrowly portrays me and thus misrepresents me as an individual. I disagree with this (or any other) label being applied to me consistently and repeatedly, and would prefer not to be labeled in *any* way.